# Parse json with jq and zip two arrays

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have the following jq command where I extract a field and create two arrays

```
jq '{
"hash_md5": .metadata[] | select(.tool == "hash") | .tool_metadata.md5,
"engine": [.assertions[] | .engine.name],
"malware": [.assertions[] | .metadata.malware_family]
}' file.json
```

As expected, I get the following output:

```
{
  "hash_md5": "799c748fe5fbc1900594d6d79bb9f803",
  "engine": [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
  ],
  "malware": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"
  ]
}
```

Now, I would like to zip the two arrays and keep the rest to arrive at:

```
{
  "hash_md5": "799c748fe5fbc1900594d6d79bb9f803",
  "assertions": [
    {
      "engine":  "A",
      "malware": "1"
    },
    {
      "engine":  "B",
      "malware": "2"
    },
    {
      "engine":  "C",
      "malware": "3"
    }]
}
```

I saw a post in which they used transpose and map, but I couldn't get it to work since I would like to keep the other fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `transpose` builtin, which converts an array of arrays into a zipped array, and `map` to generate an object within each paired array element.

```sh
jq '{
  "hash_md5": .metadata[] | select(.tool == "hash") | .tool_metadata.md5,
  "assertions": (
    [
      [.assertions[] | .engine.name],
      [.assertions[] | .metadata.malware_family]
    ]
    | transpose
    | map({"engine": .[0], "malware": .[1]})
  )
}' file.json
```

Note that, as both your arrays to be zipped result from the same iteration `.assertions[]` (which is performed twice this way), you could simply pull out the iteration and make it implicit by using a `map`:

```sh
jq '{
  "hash_md5": .metadata[] | select(.tool == "hash") | .tool_metadata.md5,
  "assertions": (
    .assertions
    | map({
        "engine": .engine.name,
        "malware": .metadata.malware_family
      })
  )
}' file.json
```

Comment: Many thanks! It works just fine! Now I understand how you can use standard parentheses () to indicate that the filter is only operating on certain fields.

Comment: @A Hansson, The parens don't do that. The simply affect precedence like in Mathematics (e.g.  `( 3 + 4 ) * 5` ). In other words, they allow `|` to be used within other expressions (just like how they allowed `+` to be used inside a term).