# JQ: Adding a single JSON object to another JSON object in order of index/corresponding order

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have two simple JSON objects, I'm trying to add a single object from a Bash variable `newValArr` in order of the corresponding objects to the `masterfile.json`. They appear as following:

`newValArr`

```
[{ "firstValue": "foo", "secondValue": "bar"},
 { "firstValue": "baz", "secondValue": "qux"},
 ...
]
```

`masterfile.json`

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "abc",
      "properties": {
        "blah": "stuff"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "def",
      "properties": {
        "blah": "morestuff"
      }
    },
...
  ]
}
```

I've created the following in Bash that adds the `firstValue` and `secondValue` object in the intended spot in the `value` array of objects, here is the script:

```
jq --argjson newvalues "${newValArr}" '.value[].properties.newObject += $newvalues[0]' masterfile.json > newoutput.json
```

And here is the current JSON output:

`newoutput.json`

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "abc",
      "properties": {
        "blah": "stuff",
        "newObject": {
          "firstValue": "foo", 
          "secondValue": "bar"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "def",
      "properties": {
        "blah": "otherstuff",
        "newObject": {
          "firstValue": "foo", 
          "secondValue": "bar"
        }
      }
    },
...
  ]
}
```

With the desired output being:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "abc",
      "properties": {
        "blah": "stuff",
        "newObject": {
          "firstValue": "foo", 
          "secondValue": "bar"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "def",
      "properties": {
        "blah": "otherstuff",
        "newObject": {
          "firstValue": "baz", 
          "secondValue": "qux"
        }
      }
    },
...
  ]
}
```

The problem obviously is that the same `newValArr` object is being placed into every single `newObject` as we're continually referencing the same index. If we don't specify the index, then all the `newValArr` objects will be placed into each `newObject`, and I'm not quite sure if it's even possible to iterate through the indexes in JQ like we would in Bash using `newValArr[@]` for example so that each index could be assigned in order. Is this possible in JQ? Or must an entirely different method be used?
The two JSON's will always have the same number of objects, in the same order, no need to worry about that.

I've looked into implementing this using to_entires, however it doesn't seem compatible with what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `to_entries` which, when applied to an array, generates indices in the `.key` field, which then can be used to index into the imported variable. Then, just `map` over the result array to construct your final objects.

```bash
jq --argjson vals "$newValArr" '.value |= (to_entries | map(
  $vals[.key] as $newObject | .value | .properties += {$newObject}
))' masterfile.json
```

```json
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "abc",
      "properties": {
        "blah": "stuff",
        "newObject": {
          "firstValue": "foo",
          "secondValue": "bar"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "def",
      "properties": {
        "blah": "morestuff",
        "newObject": {
          "firstValue": "baz",
          "secondValue": "qux"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is create a range of all the indexes of the arrays and build a new object by combining the corresponding elements:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

newValArr='
[{ "firstValue": "foo", "secondValue": "bar"},
 { "firstValue": "baz", "secondValue": "qux"}
]
'

jq -n --argjson newval "$newValArr" --argfile master masterfile.json '
   { value: [ range($master.value | length)
              | . as $n
              | $master.value[$n] * { properties: { newObject: $newval[$n] } }
            ]
   }'
```

outputs

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "abc",
      "properties": {
        "blah": "stuff",
        "newObject": {
          "firstValue": "foo",
          "secondValue": "bar"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "def",
      "properties": {
        "blah": "morestuff",
        "newObject": {
          "firstValue": "baz",
          "secondValue": "qux"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Or another approach that uses `transpose` to [zip the two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70831992/parse-json-with-jq-and-zip-two-arrays) together and then merges them:

```bash
jq --argjson newval "$newValArr" '
   .value |= [ [ ., $newval ] | transpose[] | .[0] * { properties: { newObject: .[1] }} ]
' masterfile.json
```